# Is there Vehicle Speed Errata for the DMG?

Tags: dnd-5e, travel, vehicles, errata

Recently, I have have been preparing the times for journeys over land and by sea for an upcoming session. When I told my players about my calculations, one of them said that my info in the DMG under the sailing ships speed has been Errata'd in the WotC Sage Advice blog. After hours of combing the website and google, I can find no errata specifically about vehicle speeds.
**Is there such errata?**

My google searches in regards to sailing speeds gave me the target range of 5-8 knots on average (5 knots comes in close to 6mph vs DMG saying 2mph) So if there is Errata for this I'd like to know about it so I dont unfairly slow the estimated sea voyage travel time. I know I could house rule this, but I'd prefer seeing the supposed errata this player saw a reference to on reddit. Given that it's reddit, I already doubt its legitimacy, but I'd be a terrible DM if I didn't do my due diligence and ask around for official Rulings on this stuff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The official errata for the DMG is at http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DMG-Errata.pdf. There is no amendment to ship speeds. Nor does the PHB errata http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PH-Errata.pdf.

Comment: This is still the case as of the [2018 errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DMG-Errata.pdf)

Comment: Still no mention of vehicles in the 2019 errata: https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf